The Rendered layer in Blender using camera tracking not match when import into Nuke
I'm working on an exercise about Camera Tracking and Compositing using Blender and Nuke. I have the video turned into image sequence and camera tracked it using Nuke, then I export the tracking scene as an .abc file, imported to Blender to add the 3D character and Rendered the character's layer out, in Blender it looked well tracked but when I imported the Rendered sequence into Nuke these layers weren't match. I'm not sure what caused this problem. All settings were set at the same Resolution throughout the process.



We can't really help with "Nuke" whatever that is! I'd ask in a Nuke forum if there is one or the authors of it as that appears to be where the problem is occuring from your description.
